# Add value to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a API method that is returning some question and answer as List. I need show this list in View, not sure how to add value to the faq list. As I am sending this List that is part of Model to the View to show in on the screen.

Inside the foreach loop is where I have to add value of web api to the faq List.

This is my method which is returning the Model.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowContact(int loanId)
{
    HelpCenterViewModel helpCenterViewModel = new HelpCenterViewModel();
    helpCenterViewModel.ContactInfo.loanId = loanId;
    string json = string.Empty;
    List<Faq> FaqObject = null;

    var responseApi = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/{1}", 
        CommonApiBaseUrlValue, "faqs"));
    if (responseApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        json = responseApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        FaqObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Faq>>(json);
    }
    var response = new
    {
        success = FaqObject != null,
        data = FaqObject
    };

    foreach (var faqitem in response.data)
    {
         //This is where I dont know how to add to faq list.
        //helpCenterViewModel.Faq.Answer = faqitem.Answer;
        //helpCenterViewModel.Faq.Category = faqitem.Category;

    }
    return View(helpCenterViewModel);
}
```

This is the Model that I am retunign it to view:

```
public class HelpCenterViewModel
{
    public List<Faq> Faq { get; set; }
    public ContactUsInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }

    public HelpCenterViewModel()
    {
        this.Faq = new List<Faq>();
        this.ContactInfo = new ContactUsInfo();
    }
}
```

and this is the faq class:

```
public class Faq
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my view:

```
   @model IEnum   erable<Carfinance.Loans.Web.ViewModels.HelpCenterViewModel>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
          <li>@Html.DisplayFor(faq => item.Faq)</li>
       }
```

But It gave me this error.

```
      The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'CorsMessageHandler' is not null.
```

Parameter name: handlers

Comment: I don't understand why you can't access the faq list object  inside your ViewModel and add to it?

Comment: @techspider I can access it, not sure how to add?

Comment: helpCenterViewModel.Faq.Add(faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object for each of your items and add them to your list. This can be done in various ways, depending on how verbose you want your implementation to be:

```
foreach (var faqitem in response.data)
{
     var faq = new Faq();
     faq.Answer = faqitem.Answer;
     faq.Category = faqitem.Category;

     helpCenterViewModel.Faq.Add(faq); 
}
```

OR

```
foreach (var faqitem in response.data)
     helpCenterViewModel.Faq.Add(new Faq()
     {
         Answer = faqitem.Answer;
         Category = faqitem.Category;
     });
```

OR

```
helpCenterViewModel.Faq = response.data.Select(x => new Faq { 
    Answer = x.Answer, 
    Category = x.Category
}).ToList();
```

Comment: you'd need a `ToList` on your `Select` for that to compile

Comment: @iuliu.net Thanks, that is working, but when I send it to my view not sure how to show it there.

Comment: In what kind of layout do you want your Faq to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up the code some, but you already have a `List<Faq>`, so just assign it to your model.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowContact(int loanId)
{
    string json = string.Empty;
    List<Faq> FaqObject = null;  // Should probably be new List<Faq>

    var responseApi = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/{1}", CommonApiBaseUrlValue, "faqs"));
    if (responseApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        json = responseApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        FaqObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Faq>>(json);
    }
    var response = new
    {
        success = FaqObject != null,
        data = FaqObject
    };
    return View(new HelpCenterViewModel
    {
      ContactInfo=new ContactInfo {loanId},
      Faq=FaqObject
    });
}
```

Not sure what you were doing with the `response` variable, so I just left it there, but it appears to do nothing useful and could be removed as well.  Then you'd have this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> ShowContact(int loanId)
{
    var responseApi = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}/{1}", CommonApiBaseUrlValue, "faqs"));
    if (responseApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      return View(new HelpCenterViewModel
      {
        ContactInfo=new ContactInfo {loanId},
        Faq=new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Faq>>(
          responseApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
      });
    }
    return View(new HelpCenterViewModel
    {
      ContactInfo=new ContactInfo {loanId},
      Faq=new List<Faq>()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the `Faq` property on `HelpCenterViewModel` is really a `List<Faq>` (kind of misleading naming you have there), so use the `Add` method:

```
foreach (var faqitem in response.data)
{
     var faq = new Faq();
     faq.Answer = faqitem.Answer;
     faq.Category = faqitem.Category;

     helpCenterViewModel.Faq.Add(faq); 
                        //^ this Faq is a List
}
```

You should pluralize your `List<Faq>`'s name to `Faqs` to prevent confusing yourself.